# Sharing string via AirDrop

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsstring, airdrop

I'm trying to send a string by using AirDrop. The problem is that I don't know how to use `NSURL` to send a string from `UITextField`. How can I share `NSString` from `UITextField` by using AirDrop? The following is my `IBAction` code. However, sending part is failed.

```
-(IBAction)sendButton:(id)sender { 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.inputTextField.text];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[url];

//NSLog(@"you type: %@", self.inputTextField.text);

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

// Exclude all activities except AirDrop.
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,
                                UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,  UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

// Present the controller
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

//[self.readTextView setText:self.inputTextField.text];

}
```

Comment: What happens if you share the NSString text directly?

Comment: i got it. it's work now. As i'm the beginner at ios, i do not know that i can share it directly. Thank U.

Comment: You should answer your own question then, so future visitors can benefit.

Comment: Hay @Dennis how to resolve this issue.